# useRoutes returns null but pathname is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Here is my code on React.
I have the `Component` inside a micro-frontend app, that is included into main app with module federation.

```
// inside my microfrontend.
const path = '/another-component-path';

function Component () {
  const location = useLocation();

  console.log(location.pathname === path); // this is true

  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: path,
      element: <AnotherComponent />
    }
  ]);

  console.log(routes); // this is null -- how is this possible?

  return routes;
}

export default Component;
```

The browser says "No routes matched location '/another-component-path'".

`react-router-dom` is 6.10.0

How is this possible? What is wrong?

I tried to use `Routes` and `Route` components, but it does not help.

Comment: If `Component` is rendered under `/some-route`. Your `location.pathname` needs to be `/some-path/another-component-path` to work with `useRoutes` in this configuration

Comment: In case you just missed it or haven't taken the full [tour] yet (*you earn a badge BTW*) there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Given `const path = '/another-component-path';`, if `location.pathname === path` evaluates true then this means that `Component` is rendered on path `"/another-component-path"`.

```
<Route path="/another-component-path" element={<Component />} />
```

If `Component` is rendering descendent routes, these are built ***relative*** to the parent route. In other words, with `AnotherComponent` being rendered on descendent route `path`, e.g `"/another-component-path"`, it actually resolves to `"/another-component-path/another-component-path"`.

```
function Component() {
  const location = useLocation();

  console.log(location.pathname === path); // this is true

  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: path, // <-- "/another-component-path/another-component-path"
      element: <AnotherComponent />
    }
  ]);
  return routes;
}
```

Ensure the parent route appends a trailing wildcard matchet, or splat, `"*"` to the path so descendent routes can be matched and rendered.

```
<Route path="/another-component-path/*" element={<Component />} />
```

If you would like for the `AnotherComponent` to be rendered on `"/another-component-path"`, the parent route, then its path should be `"/"` or it should be set as the index route.

```
const routes = useRoutes([
  { path: "/", element: <AnotherComponent /> }
]);
```

```
const routes = useRoutes([
  { index: true, element: <AnotherComponent /> }
]);
```

[image: Edit useroutes-returns-null-but-pathname-is-correct]

Comment: thank you, I replaced the path to "/" and it worked!

Comment: @СергейКочкин Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!